# SQL Table to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I'm using a PostgreSQL database with Psycopg2 library.
I want to get the SQL table and convert it to a pd.DataFrame.
So I need to convert SQL table to a dict like `{col1:[val1,val2], col2:[val1,val2]}` but when I use `SELECT * FROM tablename` , it doesn't include column names.
I don't want to use pandas functions directly connectiong to SQL.
If you know how to get the SQL table as a dictionary like I mentioned above, I'm happy if you write.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the column-names from the cursor in the [`description`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description)-attribute after executing a query:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename")
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
```

afterwards you should be able to parse the fetched data to a DataFrame with the correct column-names using the [`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)-argument:

```py
data_df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns=columns)
```

finally convert the DataFrame to a dictionary with lists as values using [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```py
data_dict = data_df.to_dict(orient="list")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.
I think I won't need to convert it to dictionary, because I need the dataframe. Dictionary is unnecessary.